# Adding a primary key after creating the table in sqlite

Tags: mobile, sqlite

I am making an app in which i have by mistakenly made the table without adding the primary key now i want to add primary key because it is essential for my table.I have created the table using the following command

Could you help me in this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

The new column may take any of the forms permissible in a CREATE TABLE statement, with the following restrictions:

- The column may not have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.